# Add A Watermark to a Picture [Photoshop-Script]

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photo, photoshop-script

I'm allmost new to Photoshop-scripting, and I can't seem to find very much documentation on this. I know some scripting, so please try to explain me as much as possible.

Anyhow, I need a script that'll ad to the active Picture a nother Picture as new Layer, then the proportions should be adjusted, on a way that the side edges match. The horizontal edges shoud be change in a way that the layer dont get 
distorted. Than the Program shoud set the transparency to 5% and to finish all, reduce it to the background layer.

To be honest, I have no idea how to tackle this.

Can anyone help me with this piece of code?

Comment: Unless you definitely need to do this in Photoshop, it seems like this could be done with ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick, or maybe Python's Pillow library...

Comment: I already use a Photoshop scrip, that&#39;s just a new part I wand ad to the existing. So yes it has to be Photoshop &#128517;

Comment: Could you please include an example of what you expect to get in the end in your post? I don't think I understand all the proportion changes you want to include.